# Choose optimal lags in months for annual data

Tags: model-selection, vector-autoregression, lags

I try to forecast annual monthly price changes using annual monthly X changes. To choose the best lag, I run the VAR model and aim for the minimal AIC value. The problem is that the price is determined by different factors each month, so I have to do it for each month at a time. When I run VAR in the most basic way, it returns the result without differentiating between the months. If I filter the data to include only one month, I will lose all the point of finding monthly lags.

I was thinking of modifying the data manually, each time for d lags and running it in a loop with lag=1. This would lead to the right result but would be extremely non-elegant.
Any suggestion for what I can do?
*and apologies for the basic question...*

Just for the example, I use the default `vars` dataset. It is quarterly, but imagine it is monthly. Then, I try to forecast `e` as a function of `prod`. The easiest way, which is wrong:

```r
library(vars)
test_d <- vars::Canada
vars::VARselect(y = test_d, lag.max = 11, type = "none")
```

Comment: *the price is determined by different factors each month*: are you saying the functional relationship $y=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ changes from January to February to ... and then comes back to January? $y$ is price, $x$s are different factors. So you have $y=f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ for January, $y=f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ for February, ...?

Comment: Yes, and if x1 is a factor of several months, it can have different lagged impacts. For example, high temerature, can change price of one month ahead during November but only 3 months ahead in September.

Comment: That sounds like a very complicated model, and VAR may or may not be a relevant starting point. You could try specifying it in detail in your post, though, and then perhaps we can figure something out.

Comment: Thank you for answering and editing my post. I will just modify the data in a loop, and run the model on 1 lag setting.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by modifying the data manually, and than run the `VARselect` function on the relevant lag in loops of 1 to 11. It seems to work, although it is done in a very unpretty way.

**I would appreciate any criticism.**

```r
# testing for optimal lag length (d*) based on y
# using the AIC (aim to min. AIC)
AIC <- matrix(NA, ncol = 4, nrow = 0) %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(AIC) = c("month", "feature", "lag", "AIC")

for (i in 1:12) {
  x = 1
  
  while (x <= ncol(df_all)-3) {
    feature = colnames(df_all[3+x])
    print(paste0("feature = ", feature))
    
    for(d in 1:11){
      # choose 1 X at a time and convert to TS
      test_d <- df_all[ ,c(1:3, 3+x)] %>%
        dplyr::arrange(date) %>%
        # set X d months backward, to get lagged effects
        dplyr::rename_with(~'feature', .cols = 4) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(feature = lag(feature, n = d)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(year = year(date), .after = month) %>%
        dplyr::select(-date) %>%
        drop_na()
      
      test_d <- test_d %>%
        # leave only prices of month i in the data
        dplyr::filter(month == i) %>%
        ts(start = test_d$year[1], frequency = 12)
      
      # Lag selection (with no constant, no trend)
      lag_d <- vars::VARselect(y = test_d, lag.max = d, type = "none")
      AIC[nrow(AIC)+1,] <- c(i, feature, d, lag_d$criteria[1])
    }
    x = x+1
  }
}

AIC <- AIC %>%
  dplyr::filter(AIC != "-Inf") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(AIC = as.numeric(AIC)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(month, feature) %>%
  dplyr::slice_min(AIC, n = 1)
```